# Rails 5 - Translating errors from nested model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**pt-BR.yml**:

```
pt-BR:
  activerecord:
    models:
      user: Usuário
      project: Projeto
    attributes:
      user:
        name: O nome
        description: A descrição
        projects: Os projetos
      project:
        name: O nome
  errors:
    format: "%{attribute} %{message}"
    messages:
      accepted: deve ser aceito
      blank: não pode ficar em branco
      ........
```

**Models:**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :projects, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :user

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :projects, allow_destroy: true
end

class Project < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :projects

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { mininum: 3, maximum: 255 }
end
```

**Controller:**

```
def update
  if @user.update(user_params)
    render json: @user
  else
    render json: { errors: @user.errors.full_messages }, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

All the error messages are being translated when the method `.error.full_messages` is called, except those that comes from *projects* objects (as you may have notice above, I'm using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`).

I'm always receiving the following error message:

```
{
  "errors": [
     "Projects name deve conter no mínimo 3 caracteres"
  ]      
}
```

How can I translate *Projects* and *name* in my translation file or even **remove** the "Projects %atribute%" from the error messages (without any hack)?

Answer (score 5):

For Rails 5.2 I had to check the core code to find out that it uses namespaces in the nested attribute's translation, like this:

```
  pt-BR:
    activerecord:
      attributes:
        user/projects:
          name: O nome de um projeto
```

So inside 'user/projects' node is where you can list the attributes of a Project nested in User.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the documentation: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#error-message-scopes

Notice that error name space is different from regular Model texts, you should try adding your models and attributes under error name space also to match
`activerecord.errors.models.[model_name].attributes.[attribute_name]`

```
pt-BR:
  models_and_attributes: &models_and_attributes
    models:
      user: Usuário
      project: Projeto
    attributes:
      user:
        name: O nome
        description: A descrição
        projects: Os projetos
      project:
        name: O nome
  errors:
    format: "%{attribute} %{message}"
    <<: *models_and_attributes
  activerecord:
    <<: *models_and_attributes
```